# Google Ads API - Campaign Target CPA

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am trying to get the data from table in Campaign Target CPA but doesn't work...

I tried two methods:

```
...
$dataService = $adWordsServices->get($session, DataService::class);
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(
    [
        'BidModifier',
        'CampaignId',
        'CriterionId',
        'StartDate',
        'EndDate',
        'LocalClicks',
        'LocalCost',
        'LocalImpressions',
        'TotalLocalClicks',
        'TotalLocalCost',
        'TotalLocalImpressions',
        'RequiredBudget'
    ]
);
$selector->setPredicates(
    [new Predicate('CampaignId', PredicateOperator::IN, [12334567])]
);
$result = $dataService->getCampaignCriterionBidLandscape($selector);
...
```

and

```
...
$query = sprintf(
'SELECT campaign_criterion_simulation.criterion_id, ' .
'campaign_criterion_simulation.start_date, ' .
'campaign_criterion_simulation.end_date, ' .
'campaign_criterion_simulation.bid_modifier_point_list.points ' .
'FROM campaign_criterion_simulation ' .
'WHERE campaign_criterion_simulation.campaign_id = %d',
1233456
);

$response = $googleAdsServiceClient->search($customerId, $query);
$result = $response->iterateAllElements();
...
```

I get blank data.. Please help me!

Comment: We're encountering the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes but we used selenium or cypress (js) :)